# Should I put folder .bundle under version control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I just started using bundler with rails 2.3.8. After running bundler install there is folder .bundle at the root of my project.

Should I put .bundle under version control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd leave that out of version control.  In general, adding generated files is bad - especially if they might have misleading information when someone else checks out the code.  That would definitely be true in this case.